# Grub error 21 unless both sd card and live-usb are present

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, grub-legacy

I'm not sure exactly how my EEE PC got to this point, but I have Backtrack (an Ubuntu-based distro) on the SD card, and a few different Ubuntu LiveUSB distros on different USB memory sticks.  If both the SD card and any of the USB sticks are present, the system will present a GRUB boot menu which seems to be the built-in EEE PC one--it has the "reset to factory defaults" option--but all options will boot Backtrack, even after claiming to reset to factory defaults.

If either the USB stick, the SD card, or both are missing, I get a Grub error 21 at boot.  Not sure quite how to un-hose this; I'd just like to put a conventional netbook Ubuntu on the built-in SSD, but I can't trivially do that from Backtrack 4.

Comment: Is there a BIOS setting to control boot order? Fiddling with it might solve your problem. Otherwise try running `grub-install`, perhaps after writing the [device map](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Device-map) (I don't know what would work offhand). [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) may help your diagnosis, [more about it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1291280).

Comment: I have tried all possible boot order variations in the BIOS; none affects the error 21 outcome.  The device map should only be relevant to legacy systems, but that boot info script may be useful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's a wrong setup of GRUB. Reinstall it on ssd, using uuids for booting from SD and you'll be ok.

I recommend you to install grub2 though, because it handles these situations better.